# Can a PostScript (.ps) file detect whether or not it's going to a screen (via ghostscript), as opposed to a (hardware) printer (with or without gs)?

Tags: printing, ghostscript, postscript

I wish a PostScript file to be able to behave differently depending on whether it's going to a screen (via ghostscript) or to a (hardware) printer (with or without Ghostscript). I'm thinking of things like setlinewidth, but I'm contemplating more significant differences in content.  How can this file know its ultimate destination?

Comment: Well the first point is you shouldn't try to do this. PostScript is supposed to be device-independent, and that goes for the interpreter too. If you insist on having your program behave differently then you can use the 'product' operator to get the product name. That isn't a guarantee as OEMs can change it to suit their own product line. Beyond that the only solution is heuristics. You can check for the presence of keys in systemdict or statusdict. These can change between versions of an interpreter so not guaranteed. Standard PS operators must be handled the same by all interpreters though.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that product yields 'GPL Ghostscript' for ghostscript; it's extremely unlikely that any other PostScript interpreter will use that string. It turns out that I don't just want to setlinewidth differently; I was just using that as an example. I want the content to be radically different when the user is viewing it on a screen, versus carrying away paper.

Comment: You can use Ghostscript to print too! The mswinpr2 device, for example, will print to Windows printers (your program could check the current device name to see if this is the case). Checking for 'GPL Ghostscript' should prevent false positives with commercial users since they won't have the GPL part of the string (or if they do they are quite likely to be licence infringers). There are other PostScript interpreters which will render to screen, though these days not very many it is true.

Comment: The goal in this case is to test whether the output is to the screen or to a printer. In the UNIXoid context, if Ghostscript is going to the screen, then 'currentpagedevice /Name get (x11) anchorsearch' will yield true (plus other stuff on the stack) if and only if you're going to the screen. If you're going elsewhere (either through Ghostscript or directly), then either it yields false (plus other stack stuff) or it blows up because /Name isn't in currentpagedevice; you can use the 'known' operator to guard against this or (if you're a masochist) the 'stopped' operator.